# Fullcalendar won't display JSON objects using resource

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm working with fullcalendar and I want use a JSON file to load my resource. The JSON is a URL that returns the objects.

The JSON file:

```
[
  {id: '001995',title: 'Victor'},
  {id: '000078',title: 'Jhon'}
]
```

Code sample

```
        resources: {
            url: '/resource-agenda/resource.json',
            type: 'POST'},
        events: '/resource-agenda/event.json'
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the problem with the code below:

```
resources: { // you can also specify a plain string like 'json/resources.json'
            url: 'resource-agenda/resource.json',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            }
        },

        events: { // you can also specify a plain string like 'json/events.json'
            url: 'resource-agenda/event.json',
            error: function() {
                $('#script-warning').show();
            }
        }
```